# The Gases, Metals, and Medals from Mass Effect 1... Do they have an effect on ME2?

Tags: mass-effect

I just finished playing Mass Effect 1 and completed and now am restarting it to finish up to level 60.

I noticed that the entire journal is emptied out meaning that I have to, sadly, recollect all the extras from the assignment missions.

Before I start grinding through the game for a second time, is there any benefit to completing these missions when transferring the save to Mass Effect 2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the Mass Effect Wiki, it doesn't appear that any bonuses are granted for finishing with a large amount of resources.  It looks like the only attributes that are considered are your level and the Rich achievement, if you obtained that.

Reference here: http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Save_File_Transfer#Character_Transfer